# dblink doesn't use the .pgpass file

Tags: postgresql, authentication, dblink

I do not know what is wrong with my settings, but when I try to connect to a database with

```
psql -h {db address} -U {username} -w {db name}
```

It works fine, so the .pgpass file is OK.
But if I connect to the local DB, and try this:

```
select dblink_connect_u( 'conName', 'hostaddr={address} port={port} dbname={dbName} user={userName} ' );
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

With password in the connection string, it works well, but I do not want the password to be visible by anyone.
Any idea why is this doing this?

Postgres version : 9.3

**Edit:**
OS: postgres is running on my computer(win7) and on the remote server too(Ubuntu server 14.04). In Windows, the pgpass.conf file is : Users/Myuser/AppData/Roaming/postgres/pgpass.conf, on Ubuntu: /var/lib/postgres/.pgpass
But I've tried with Ubuntu on both local and remote server too, with the same .pgpass location, and the postgres process is running as postgres user, but the result is the same.

.pgpass file content:

192.168.1.47:5432:*:remoteusername:remotepassword
192.168.1.46:5432:*:localusername:localpassword

The two databases are not on the same machine.

**Update**
It seems to be an IP address resolve problem, because when I try the `dblink_conncet_u()` with `'hostaddr=ip_address_here'` it is not working. But when I put the hostname in the `.pgpass` file instead of the IP address, and in the connection string I use `'host=hostname_here'` it works fine.

Comment: You are not providing any of the essential details. Postgres version, OS, the content of your .pgpass file. Are you connecting to the same db cluster on the same port on the same maschine? Etc.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You are right. Post has been updated.

Comment: Where is the `.pgpass` located? On the client computer (where you run the SQL) or the server (where Postgres is running)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Post edited. But there are no problem with the .pgpass file. when I use the `psql` command with `-w` . Only the `dblink_connect_u` has this problem. I know I could edit the pg_hba.conf file on the target server to trust my IP, but it is not a well solution either.

Answer (score 1):

Now then, `db_link()` will be running on the backend server process as user postgres.

Is your `.pgpass` file in the correct place for user postgres on the database machine?

If not, how do you expect it to be read?

---

I think you must have missed something:

```
# ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass 
-rw------- 1 root root 79 Jun 24 08:10 /var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass

(meanwhile, in psql...)
dblinklocal=# SELECT dblink_connect('conn1', 'hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=dblinkremote user=testuser');
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  fe_sendauth: no password supplied

# chown postgres:postgres .pgpass
dblinklocal=# SELECT dblink_connect('conn1', 'hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=dblinkremote user=testuser');
 dblink_connect 
----------------
 OK
(1 row)
```

Comment: The .pgpass file is located in the /var/lib/postgres/ which is the home dir of user postgres. And the file mode is set to 0600. 
The postgres process is running as user postgres on both machine.
And the two .pgpass file content is the same.

Comment: Yeah, I must have missed something, but not this.   
  
`# ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass  
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 163 jun   24 09:40/var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass`  
It is owned by postgres user and group, the problem is not there.