# How to use dblink with out password in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, password-encryption, dblink

My main concern is having passwords in the script (Postgres function), I am looking for a solution that how can avoid using passwords in Postgres functions.

I have a problem with using `dblink_connect()` in my function.
When I provide the password in the connection string, there is no problem, but when I don’t, it says:

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

However the `.pgpass` file in the path `/var/lib/postgres/.pgpass` does contain the proper password.

I have tried to connect to another database in the same server using dblink with psql from bash with the following command:

```sh
psql –h localhost –U myuser –w remote_db_name
```

It works fine.

My .pgpass file does have the line:

```
Localhost:5432:*:myuser:mypassword
```

It seems the psql finds the proper password in the .pgpass file but dblink doesn’t.

Comment: You need to put that password into the `.pgass` file on the _server_, not your local computer. And it needs to be in the home directory of the operating system user running the Postgres services (to usually `postgres`)

Comment: Does [dblink doesn't use the .pgpass file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991825/dblink-doesnt-use-the-pgpass-file) (IP vs. hostname) help?

Comment: You say you have a problem using dblink_connect in your function.  What if you just use it directly outside a function?

Comment: In my hands 'localhost' is case sensitive (in .pgpass).  Did you really spell it 'Localhost'?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, found out that you can actually ged rid of hardcoding database credentials in dblink query if you use the combination of dblink + postgres_fdw.

Using postgres_fdw you can create a foreign server connection and a user mapping to it, and after that you can just put a server name as  a first argument. So in such a way you don't need to neigher hardcode anything, or worry about masking it if you run in in Airflow, for example.

It's a simple approach and it's described in more detail here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60603078/4643681) to another question, not to copy-paste code from there.